# How to replace column value based on another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

I have a df1

```
index | Institute
-----------------
0     | P001
-----------------
1     | P002
-----------------
2     | P001
-----------------
3     | Clinic C
```

I also have df2

```
CODE    | Clinic
--------------------
P001    | Clinic A
--------------------
P002     | Clinic B
```

I would like to map df1 with df2 and the resulting df1 should be

```
index | Clinic
------------------
0     | Clinic A
------------------
1     | Clinic B
------------------
2     | Clinic A
------------------
3     | Clinic C
```

I hope I can make sense. Sorry if its not. First time asking question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) - values of `CODE` column have to be unique:

```
#if CODE is index need s = df2['Clinic']
s = df2.set_index('CODE')['Clinic']
df1['Institute'] = df1['Institute'].replace(s)
print (df1)
   index Institute
0      0  Clinic A
1      1  Clinic B
2      2  Clinic A
3      3  Clinic C
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked! will learn to phrase my question better :)